# How to implemente ajax Tabs and Google Charts in Yii2

Tags: ajax, yii2, google-visualization

I am trying to implement Google Charts in (ajax) tabs in order to build charts dynamically when the user click on each tab. I'm using Yii2 and (kartik) [TabX widget](https://demos.krajee.com/tabs-x) for the tabs ajax functionality. I used these 2 widgets for Google Charts:

- [bsadnu / yii2-googlecharts](https://github.com/bsadnu/yii2-googlecharts)
- [ScottHuangZL / yii2-google-chart](https://github.com/ScottHuangZL/yii2-google-chart)

My own widgets do render well. The data I send ($ data), is displayed correctly with a var_dump (). But the Google Chart does not appear.

Following the instructions in the TabX documentation I have done the following:

**In my Constructor:**

```
public function actionFetchTabs($tab=1) {                

    $html = '';
    switch($tab) {                        
        case 1:
            // ...
        case 2:
            $html = $this->renderPartial('empresa_charts', ['data'=>$this->getData()]);
            break;
    }      
    return Json::encode($html);
}
```

**In my view:**

```
<?= TabsX::widget([
    'encodeLabels' => false,
    'options' => ['class' => 'charts-tab'],
    'position'=>TabsX::POS_ABOVE,        
    'items' => [        
        [
            // NO ajax: Renders fine!
            'label' => Icon::show('chart-pie').'Label 1',
            'content' => Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('default_charts',['data'=>$data2]),                
            'active' => $tab == 1,
        ],
        [
            // Ajax: Google Charts isn't rendering:
            'label' => Icon::show('clipboard-list').'Empresas',
            //What do I have to pass in content????? The documentation is not accurate.
            'content' => ???               
            'linkOptions'=>['data-url'=>Url::to(['default/fetch-tabs?tab=2'])],             
            'active' => $tab == 2,
        ],            
    ],
]);?>
```

The data is being passed correctly. My widget render without problems with the same data array. If I pass the renderPartial directly to the "content" property of the Tabx widget, everything works (as in Tab1) because everything is loaded at the same time when loading the page.

[image]

This problem occurs with the 2 widgets for Google Charts mentioned above. I begin to suspect that the problem is in **Google Charts and Json encode**.

Any help?

Comment: could you not load the data and chart via javascript when the tab is clicked?

Comment: have you tried with `renderAjax` instead of `renderPartial` ?

Comment: using a normal html view with the scripts loaded inside the charts load correctly witht he tabsX widget i recon that the widget you are using are the reason they are not working

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Yes. I tried. And the result is the same.

@ WhiteHat It is likely to work if I do it from Javascript, but I intended to do so using Yii2 widgets.

HTML and my custom ajax. I guess I'll have to do something like that.

Thanks for the comments.